# Counting the amount of selected buttons in a swift array

Tags: arrays, swift, button, toggle, selected

I have 4 custom-made toggle buttons. Users can select multiple buttons and toggle the same button, however, there must always be at least 1 selected button.

If 1 out of 4 buttons are selected, then the selected button can not be toggled to become deselected.

I am looking for a way to determine this logic. My thought was to simply count the selected items in the button array, and if there is only 1 selected, then escape via return.

**Here's my progress**

```
func toggleButton(button: ToggleButton){
    
    let buttonArray = [btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4]
    for btn in buttonArray{
        // Count the amount of selected buttons in buttonArray
        // if 1, return.
    }
    
    button.isSelected = !button.isSelected
}
```

**Is there a way to count the amount of selected buttons in buttonArray?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a variable `numberOfSelected` to keep track of the number of selected buttons? And if it's equal to 1, return:

```
var numberOfSelected = 0
let buttonArray = [btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4]
for btn in buttonArray {
    if btn.isSelected {
        numberOfSelected += 1
    }
}
if numberOfSelected == 1 { return } /// escape via return
```

Answer (score 0):

In my playground with:

```
struct ToggleButton {
    let isSelected: Bool
}
let btn1 = ToggleButton(isSelected: true)
let btn2 = ToggleButton(isSelected: false)
let btn3 = ToggleButton(isSelected: false)
let btn4 = ToggleButton(isSelected: true)
let buttonArray = [btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4]
```

I can do:

```
let count = buttonArray // 2
    .filter(\.isSelected)
    .map { _ in 1 }
    .reduce(0, +)
```

or:

```
let otherCount = buttonArray // 2 
    .filter(\.isSelected)
    .reduce(0) { count, _ in
        count.advanced(by: 1)
    }
```

But if what you **really** want to know is if at least one button is selected you can directly do :

```
let atLeastOneButtonSelected = !buttonArray
    .map(\.isSelected)
    .filter { $0 }
    .isEmpty
```